# Differences Between Building a Custom Blog vs Building a Blog on Blogger

Tags: domains, blog, blogger

I just wanted to if there is any difference between building a custom blog (i.e. blog with purchased domain and host) and building a blog on blogger. I mean with a blog on blogger, you can create posts, pages, add ads etc. and the same thing you can do with a hosted blog with WordPress installation. Then why would someone spend money on creating something that you can create for free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic answer comes likely down to control. Google has complete control over the Blogger platform, which leaves users at it's mercy.

As a few examples:

- To comply with European Union rules, they automatically place a "Use of Cookies" notice on the site.
- Blogger places adult sites behind a warning interstitial.
- Blogger doesn't allow adult sites with ads.
- [Blogger has a large number of rules regarding content](https://www.blogger.com/content.g?hl=en). To be fair, many hosting platforms have similar rules. But with non-blogger sites you can switch hosting if you wish. With Blogger, your stuck with that service to a degree.
- If Blogger doesn't provide a feature or service, there is no way to add it.
- If something breaks, there are perhaps more avenues for solving the problem with smaller players than a multinational corporation.